# Поиск ближайшей станции метро

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Приветствую, работаю с Яндекс.Картами, понадобилась найти ближайшую станцию метро.
Имеются координаты точек, нужно найти ближайшую станцию от этих точек. Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким решение?

```js
multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
    referencePoints: [
        [lat, lon], // Координаты А
        "Москва, ул. Мясницкая" // Координаты B
    ],
    params: {
        results: 2
    }
    }, {
        boundsAutoApply: true
    }
)
```

Строю маршрут пока что так.

Answer (score 3):

В песочнице JS API Яндекс Карт есть пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/reverse_geocode

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
            zoom: 9
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        });

    // Поиск станций метро.
    ymaps.geocode(myMap.getCenter(), {
        /**
         * Опции запроса
         * @see https://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/geocode.xml
         */
        // Ищем только станции метро.
        kind: 'metro',
        // Запрашиваем не более 20 результатов.
        results: 20
    }).then(function (res) {
            // Задаем изображение для иконок меток.
            res.geoObjects.options.set('preset', 'islands#redCircleIcon');
            res.geoObjects.events
                // При наведении на метку показываем хинт с названием станции метро.
                .add('mouseenter', function (event) {
                    var geoObject = event.get('target');
                    myMap.hint.open(geoObject.geometry.getCoordinates(), geoObject.getPremise());
                })
                // Скрываем хинт при выходе курсора за пределы метки.
                .add('mouseleave', function (event) {
                    myMap.hint.close(true);
                });
            // Добавляем коллекцию найденных геообъектов на карту.
            myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects);
            // Масштабируем карту на область видимости коллекции.
            myMap.setBounds(res.geoObjects.getBounds());
        });
}
```